# Append dictionary into EXCEL file by python

Tags: python, csv, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

> This is my function, by using this i am trying to create(if file not exist) or append the dictionary into file.

```
headers = dict.keys()


if not os.path.isfile('metrics1.csv'):
    with open('metrics1.csv', 'w')as csv_file:
        csv_file.writelines(', '.join(headers))


if not os.path.isfile('metrics1.xlsx'):
    book = xlsxwriter.Workbook('metrics1.xlsx')
    sheet = book.add_worksheet("TestSheet")
    for (idx, header) in enumerate(headers):
        sheet.write(0, idx, header)
    book.close()


with open('metrics1.csv', 'a+') as csv_file:
    book = load_workbook('metrics1.xlsx')
    sheet = book.get_sheet_by_name('TestSheet')


    for d in dict:
        values = [d[key] for key in headers]
        csv_string = '\n'+', '.join(values)
        csv_file.write(csv_string)
        sheet.append(values)
    book.save(filename='metrics1.xlsx')
```

> i got following error,

```
  values = [d[key] for key in headers]
  TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: What is the elements in `headers`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix several things. First and foremost, do not name any variables `dict`.  `dict` is a python built-in keyword.  We'll assume that you've renamed it `data` in the code below.

Second, you can create your headers list a little more easily:

```
headers = list(data.keys())  #  or [ key for key in data ]
```

Third, and finally, is the line where you want to extract value from a dictionary:

```
values = [data[key] for key in headers]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: No , it gives this ,

Comment: csv_string = '\n'+', '.join(values)
TypeError: sequence item 2: expected str instance, int found

Comment: Python is pretty good when it comes to explaining what the issue is. I don't know what the various values are in the `values` list but looking at the error message I'm assuming you're trying to add `string` to an `int`. 
Check what's in that list. Modifying this line might help: `values = [str(data[key]) for key in headers]`